R: Assigning different coefficient estimates to different panels in regression table
I am running 2SLS model and want to build a panel that shows the estimates for different regressors for the first stage, the second stage and the reduced form.
The table below shows what I want (table is taken form Harris (2022)). The panel shows some regressors for the second-stage and different ones for the first-stage and the reduced form.
(https://i.sstatic.net/jyp8kTgF.png)
I want to do the same but I'm not able to hide the estimates of some regressors in some panels but not in others.
I use different data, but I try to build a minimal reproducible example here: 
(Example and Code is from Huntingotn-Klein (2022))
library(tidyverse)
library(fixest)
library(modelsummary)

d <- causaldata::social_insure

# basic model
m1 <- feols(takeup_survey ~ male 
            | pre_takeup_rate ~ default, 
            cluster = ~address, data = d)

# model with some controls
m2 <- feols(takeup_survey ~ male + age + agpop + ricearea_2010 +
             literacy + intensive + risk_averse + disaster_prob +
             factor(village) | pre_takeup_rate ~ default, 
           cluster = ~address, data = d)

# reduced form
rf1 <- feols(takeup_survey ~ default +
               male, 
               cluster = ~address, data = d)

rf2 <- feols(takeup_survey ~ default + 
               male + age + agpop + ricearea_2010 +
              literacy + intensive + risk_averse + disaster_prob +
              factor(village) , 
            cluster = ~address, data = d)

This is what I get using the modelsummarymodelsummary package

# Goodness of fit
gm <- tibble::tribble(
  ~raw,        ~clean,          ~fmt,
  "nobs",      "Number of Observations",             0)

modelsummary(pnl, shape = "rbind", 
             gof_map = gm,
             coef_map = c(fit_pre_takeup_rate = 'Friends Purchase Behavior',
                          age = "Age", 
                          default = 'Instrument'))



Right now each panel displays the estimates for Age and the number of observations. However, I only want the estimates for Age to appear in the Panel "2SLS" and the number of observations in the last row of the last panel.
# Right now the table looks like this, which is not what I want
+---------------------------+---------+---------+
|                           | (1)     | (2)     |
+===========================+=========+=========+
| 2SLS                                          |
+---------------------------+---------+---------+
| Friends Purchase Behavior | 0.727   | 0.791   |
+---------------------------+---------+---------+
|                           | (0.209) | (0.273) |
+---------------------------+---------+---------+
| Age                       |         | 0.005   |
+---------------------------+---------+---------+
|                           |         | (0.001) |
+---------------------------+---------+---------+
| Number of Observations    | 1407    | 1378    |
+---------------------------+---------+---------+
| First-Stage                                   |
+---------------------------+---------+---------+
| Age                       |         | 0.000   |
+---------------------------+---------+---------+
|                           |         | (0.000) |
+---------------------------+---------+---------+
| Instrument                | 0.145   | 0.118   |
+---------------------------+---------+---------+
|                           | (0.036) | (0.034) |
+---------------------------+---------+---------+
| Number of Observations    | 1407    | 1378    |
+---------------------------+---------+---------+
| Reduced Form                                  |
+---------------------------+---------+---------+
| Age                       |         | 0.006   |
|---------------------------+---------+---------+
|                           |         | (0.001) |
+---------------------------+---------+---------+
| Instrument                | 0.105   | 0.093   |
+---------------------------+---------+---------+
|                           | (0.034) | (0.030) |
+---------------------------+---------+---------+
| Number of Observations    | 1407    | 1378    |
+---------------------------+---------+---------+ 

EDIT: More precisely,I want an output table that shows the following regressors:
For the panels "2SLS" the regressors "Friends Purchase Behaviour" and "Age" should appear. For the panels "First Stage" and "Reduced Form" only the regressor "Instrument" should appear. The "Number of Observations" should only appear once at the end of the table. I will edit my question with this clarification.

+---------------------------+---------+---------+
|                           | (1)     | (2)     |
+===========================+=========+=========+
| 2SLS                                          |
+---------------------------+---------+---------+
| Friends Purchase Behavior | 0.727   | 0.791   |
+---------------------------+---------+---------+
|                           | (0.209) | (0.273) |
+---------------------------+---------+---------+
| Age                       |         | 0.005   |
+---------------------------+---------+---------+
|                           |         | (0.001) |
+---------------------------+---------+---------+
| First-Stage                                   |
+---------------------------+---------+---------+
| Instrument                | 0.145   | 0.118   |
+---------------------------+---------+---------+
|                           | (0.036) | (0.034) |
+---------------------------+---------+---------+
| Reduced Form                                  |
+---------------------------+---------+---------+
| Instrument                | 0.105   | 0.093   |
+---------------------------+---------+---------+
|                           | (0.034) | (0.030) |
+---------------------------+---------+---------+
| Number of Observations    | 1407    | 1378    |
+---------------------------+---------+---------+ 

I used modelsummary for all my other output tables, but if there is a better alternative, such as panelsummary or stargazer, please let me know.

You can do something like this
library(fixest)
library(modelsummary)

d <- causaldata::social_insure


gm <- tibble::tribble(
  ~raw,        ~clean,          ~fmt,
  "nobs",      "Number of Observations",             0)

panels = list(
  "2SLS" = list("I" = feols(takeup_survey ~ male + age + agpop + ricearea_2010 +
                              literacy + intensive + risk_averse + disaster_prob +
                              factor(village) | pre_takeup_rate ~ default, 
                            cluster = ~address, data = d)),
  "Reduced Form" = list("I" = feols(takeup_survey ~ default + 
                                      male + age + agpop + ricearea_2010 +
                                      literacy + intensive + risk_averse + disaster_prob +
                                      factor(village) , 
                                    cluster = ~address, data = d)),
  "First Stage" = list("I" = summary(feols(takeup_survey ~ male + age + agpop + ricearea_2010 +
                                             literacy + intensive + risk_averse + disaster_prob +
                                             factor(village) | pre_takeup_rate ~ default, 
                                           cluster = ~address, data = d), stage = 1))
)
#> NOTE: 32 observations removed because of NA values (RHS: 32).
#> NOTE: 32 observations removed because of NA values (RHS: 32).
#> NOTE: 32 observations removed because of NA values (RHS: 32).

modelsummary(panels,
             shape = 'rbind',
             gof_map = gm,
             coef_map = c(fit_pre_takeup_rate = 'Friends Purchase Behavior',
                          age = "Age", 
                          default = 'Instrument'))





I




2SLS



Friends Purchase Behavior
0.791



(0.273)


Age
0.005



(0.001)


Number of Observations
1378


Reduced Form



Age
0.006



(0.001)


Instrument
0.093



(0.030)


Number of Observations
1378


First Stage



Age
0.000



(0.000)


Instrument
0.118



(0.034)


Number of Observations
1378



Created on 2024-07-19 with reprex v2.1.1

Thank you for your answer @Josh. Unfortunately it seems that I did not express myself clearly. I want an output table that shows the following regressors:
For the panels "2SLS" the regressors "Friends Purchase Behaviour" and "Age" should appear. For the panels "First Stage" and "Reduced Form" the regressor "Instrument" should appear. The "Number of Observations" should only appear once at the end of the table. I will edit my question with this clarification.
